# Remove certain rows with some conditions (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, multiple-columns

create a dataframe df2 : keep the row if the value1, value2, value3 are NaN and

create a dataframe df3:  keep the row if value5, value6, value7 are NaN

Input Dataframe, df:

```
    name    value1  value2  value3  value4  value5 value6   value7  value8  value9
0   58390   28.4    32.2    31.3    30.6    40.7    40.0    39.6    40.10   NaN
1   58395   31.4    32.8    31.5    31.9    NaN NaN NaN 38.60   NaN
2   67488   NaN NaN NaN 26.6    NaN NaN NaN 34.90   NaN
3   67490   NaN NaN NaN 29.9    NaN NaN NaN 39.65   NaN
4   67501   NaN NaN NaN 20.5    NaN NaN NaN 27.10   NaN
```

Output Dataframe df2:

```
    name    value1  value2  value3  value4  value5 value6   value7  value8  value9
0   67488   NaN NaN NaN 26.6    NaN NaN NaN 34.90   NaN
1   67490   NaN NaN NaN 29.9    NaN NaN NaN 39.65   NaN
2   67501   NaN NaN NaN 20.5    NaN NaN NaN 27.10   NaN
```

Output Dataframe df3:

```
    name    value1  value2  value3  value4  value5 value6   value7  value8  value9
0   58395   31.4    32.8    31.5    31.9    NaN NaN NaN 38.60   NaN
1   67488   NaN NaN NaN 26.6    NaN NaN NaN 34.90   NaN
2   67490   NaN NaN NaN 29.9    NaN NaN NaN 39.65   NaN
3   67501   NaN NaN NaN 20.5    NaN NaN NaN 27.10   NaN
```

create a dataframe df2 : keep the row if the value1, value2, value3 are NaN and

create a dataframe df3:  keep the row if value5, value6, value7 are NaN

Input Dataframe, df:

```
    name    value1  value2  value3  value4  value5 value6   value7  value8  value9
0   58390   28.4    32.2    31.3    30.6    40.7    40.0    39.6    40.10   NaN
1   58395   31.4    32.8    31.5    31.9    NaN NaN NaN 38.60   NaN
2   67488   NaN NaN NaN 26.6    NaN NaN NaN 34.90   NaN
3   67490   NaN NaN NaN 29.9    NaN NaN NaN 39.65   NaN
4   67501   NaN NaN NaN 20.5    NaN NaN NaN 27.10   NaN
```

Output Dataframe df2:

```
    name    value1  value2  value3  value4  value5 value6   value7  value8  value9
0   67488   NaN NaN NaN 26.6    NaN NaN NaN 34.90   NaN
1   67490   NaN NaN NaN 29.9    NaN NaN NaN 39.65   NaN
2   67501   NaN NaN NaN 20.5    NaN NaN NaN 27.10   NaN
```

Output Dataframe df3:

```
    name    value1  value2  value3  value4  value5 value6   value7  value8  value9
0   58395   31.4    32.8    31.5    31.9    NaN NaN NaN 38.60   NaN
1   67488   NaN NaN NaN 26.6    NaN NaN NaN 34.90   NaN
2   67490   NaN NaN NaN 29.9    NaN NaN NaN 39.65   NaN
3   67501   NaN NaN NaN 20.5    NaN NaN NaN 27.10   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) and [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) in a list comprehension.

As you want to do this repeatedly, better use a list to collect the output:

```
cols = [['value1', 'value2', 'value3'],
        ['value5', 'value6', 'value7']]

out = [df[df[c].isna().all(axis=1)] for c in cols]
```

Output:

```
[    name  value1  value2  value3  value4  value5  value6  value7  value8  value9
 2  67488     NaN     NaN     NaN    26.6     NaN     NaN     NaN   34.90     NaN
 3  67490     NaN     NaN     NaN    29.9     NaN     NaN     NaN   39.65     NaN
 4  67501     NaN     NaN     NaN    20.5     NaN     NaN     NaN   27.10     NaN,

     name  value1  value2  value3  value4  value5  value6  value7  value8  value9
 1  58395    31.4    32.8    31.5    31.9     NaN     NaN     NaN   38.60     NaN
 2  67488     NaN     NaN     NaN    26.6     NaN     NaN     NaN   34.90     NaN
 3  67490     NaN     NaN     NaN    29.9     NaN     NaN     NaN   39.65     NaN
 4  67501     NaN     NaN     NaN    20.5     NaN     NaN     NaN   27.10     NaN]
```